# Can I invalidate an RTK query from a different slice of my store?

Tags: rtk-query

I have a store with different slices, I'm using (awesome) RTK query and in one of my slices I need to invalidate data from another. Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can do the invalidation inside the endpoint definition with something like this.

Basically, otherServiceApi is the other slice you want to invalidate, where the invalidation will be called once the API call has finished (api.queryFulfilled.then)

```js
deleteUser: builder.mutation<DeleteUserRes, DeleteUserParams>({
  query: ({ id }) => ({
    url: `user/${id}`,
    method: "DELETE",
  }),
  onQueryStarted: (arg, api) => {
    api.queryFulfilled.then(() => {
      api.dispatch(
        otherServiceApi.util.invalidateTags(["your-tag", "your-tag-2"])
      );
    });
  },
});
```

You can also call the invalidation anywhere. If inside the React component, you can do:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch()
dispatch(otherServiceApi.util.invalidateTags(["your-tag"]))
```

Or if on plain TS/JS function:

```js
store.dispatch(otherServiceApi.util.invalidateTags(["your-tag"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a mutation which invalidates tags you need and then call that mutation from anywhere you want.

from rtk-query docs:

```
refetchErroredQueries: build.mutation<null, void>({
  queryFn: () => ({ data: null }),
  invalidatesTags: ['UNKNOWN_ERROR'],
}),
```

more at [Providing errors to the cache](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching#providing-errors-to-the-cache)

Comment: I tried that in one slice and it's not working to invalidate the other slide's tag